# Java not running even after installation in Ubuntu

Tags: java

I tried installing every jdks the system suggested but even after I couldn't run a single program
I reinstalled the jdks repeatedly an there is no mistake with that. Even then it says "javac is available in the following packages"

Comment: How are you trying running them and what exact error message are you getting?

Comment: javac not fo running, but for compiling...

Comment: Needs **a lot** more details: What **exact** packages have you installed? What's the **exact** command you executed? What's the **exact** error message you get? Without that information we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Check if java binary is in path. You may try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable. If you have not yet tried, you may try installing JDK from https://adoptopenjdk.net/. This installation automatically sets path for you.